# DisplayPort daisy chain not working

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, external-display, daisychaining

I have two [Dell UltraSharp U2715H](http://accessories.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&sku=210-ADKB) screens, supporting DisplayPort 1.2 and daisy chaining. I have confirmed this by connecting them together in a daisy chain, and connecting the first monitor to my Surface 2 Pro. It work beautifully.

My laptop is a [Dell Latitude E6520](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/latitude-e6520/pd), which does not have a DisplayPort. I want to use the two monitors with this laptop, and have therefore bought a [Dell Port Replicator EURO 2 Simple E-Port II](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=nl&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Faccessories.euro.dell.com%2Fsna%2Fproductdetail.aspx%3Fc%3Dnl%26l%3Dnl%26s%3Ddhs%26cs%3Dnldhs1%26sku%3D452-11422&sandbox=1) docking station. I was not able to find an English page describing the exact part number 452-11422, but the linked Google Translated page clearly displays DisplayPort 1.2 as a key feature.

However, when I connect the first monitor to the docking station, both monitors show the same image. They are detected as only one monitor by Windows 8.1, and the image that is sent to the first monitor is just passed on to the daisy chained monitor as well. In Device Manager, only one monitor is listed in addition to the internal laptop monitor.

Can it be that the graphics card in my laptop does not support daisy chaining? I have updated it with the latest driver from Nvidia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the Graphics on the laptop doesn't support daisy chaining, even though the Port Replicator does.

From your link - [Dell Port Replicator EURO 2 Simple E-Port II](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=nl&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Faccessories.euro.dell.com%2Fsna%2Fproductdetail.aspx%3Fc%3Dnl%26l%3Dnl%26s%3Ddhs%26cs%3Dnldhs1%26sku%3D452-11422&sandbox=1)

> For serial connection of monitors (4 monitors through one connector)
>   - Supported only with discrete graphics on current generation of Latitude laptops

Current generation would be Intel 5000 series graphics [+ optimus]; your machine is only Intel 3000.